# dynamic search with operator like in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, operator-keyword

I am new with Meteor and MongoDB.  I want to ask how to search data dynamically in MongoDB. My attempt is:

```
Template.MainTemplate.ItemsFounded = function() {
    return ITEM.find({ItemName:{$regex: Session.get('SearchItemName')}});
};

Template.TemplateSearchItem.events({
    'click .SearchItem' : function() {
        var $itemName =  $('#TextboxSearchItemName');
        Session.set('SearchItemName', '/'+ $itemName.val()+ '/');
    }
});
```

when it runs, it display nothing.. can someone help me? sorry for my silly question..

thanks

Comment: What is `Template.MainTemplate.ItemsFounded` ? You probably want some thing like `Template.MainTemplate.helpers({ itemsFound: function() { return ITEM.find({ItemName:{$regex: Session.get('SearchItemName')}}); }});`

Then in the your MainTemplate: {{#each itemsFound}} ...do something with the results... {{/each}}

Comment: yes.. i subtitute the helpers with the Template.MainTemplate.ItemsFounded.. it works now.. but i have a new question.. and its already submited in Guillaume post below..

Answer (score 2):

The problem could come from the fact that you are not building a regex but a simple String with this:

```
Session.set('SearchItemName', '/'+ $itemName.val()+ '/');
```

In order to build a regex you should create a new `RegExp` object to be use in the Mongo `$regex`query. You should also rewrite "ItemsFounded" as it is not the proper way to declare helpers in Meteor:

```
Template.TemplateSearchItem.events({
  'click .SearchItem' : function() {
    var $itemName =  $('#TextboxSearchItemName');
    Session.set('SearchItemName', $itemName.val());
  }
});
...
Template.MainTemplate.helpers({
  ItemsFounded: function() {
    var regex = new RegExp(Session.get('SearchItemName'), 'i'); //'i' for case insensitive search
    return ITEM.find({ItemName:{$regex: regex}});
  }      
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need to supply a RegExp object to a mongo $regex query (or if you can?), but you shouldn't have the forward-slashes if you're just passing it a string. So just `Session.set('SearchItemName', $itemName.val());` should work.

Comment: I am always using `new RegExp` when querying with $regexp in MongoDB and it works.

Comment: But did not notice the error in the OP's template :)

Comment: In that case either of our suggestions will work :) I think the main problem here is probably that the OP isn't using a helper to display the results.

Comment: Hi Gillaume, i've follow your instruction and its working.. but i want to ask something.. first is how does the regex work ? im not using any forward slash anymore but it works just LIKE operator in SQL.. what if i want to go with such LIKE 'a%'.. the second is, if we want to display the result, is the template.helper is only the solution ?

Comment: The RegExp object take care of the '/' for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp. Because you cannot build directly a regex with a variable enclosed in /. Concerning the equivalent to LIKE 'a%' you can either use `string.*` ("string" followed by any character) or `^string.*` (starting with "string" and followed by any character):  `new RegExp(Session.get('SearchItemName')+'.*', 'i');` or `new RegExp('^' + Session.get('SearchItemName')+'.*', 'i');`.

Comment: And concerning your last question, you will need a helper if you want to be able to display the result in a template with {{ItemsFounded}}